# How to execute PERFORM pg_notify('', '')?

Tags: postgresql, notify

When I execute `PERFORM pg_notify('channel', 'payload');` I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PERFORM"
LINE 1: PERFORM pg_notify('channel', 'payload');
        ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

The `SELECT` counterpart works, but I'm looking for a no-result equivalent. And I'm using `psql (9.5.3, server 9.5.0)`.

Comment: Can you share some more of the outer code?

Comment: There's no outer code. I'm executing this line in `psql` directly.

Comment: I can't find any mention of `pg_notify()` working with `PERFORM` and I am also unable to get it to work.

Comment: I found the problem, I'll post it in a bit.

Comment: In `psql` use `\o /dev/null` to suppress whole output and `\o` to restore output to the `stdout`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here relies on the fact that `PERFORM` can not be executed directly within the prompt. As the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) says:

> Sometimes it is useful to evaluate an expression or SELECT query but
>   discard the result, for example when calling a function that has
>   side-effects but no useful result value. To do this in **PL/pgSQL**, use
>   the PERFORM statement:

It's a little bit tricky but `PERFORM` can only be used in a **PL/pgSQL** context (functions, stored procedures and stuff). And I was trying to execute it directly in the prompt which is not supported.